# How to print out the access right from linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, lsof

When I run the command lsof from a terminal, it will show a detail list of all file descriptor with a header is FD. And FD column numbers like 1u is actual file descriptor and followed by u,r,w of it’s mode as:

- r for read access
- w for write access
- u for read and write access

My question is how to print out these types of access from a linux kernel module?
I am able to print the files_path (See the attracted picture). And I see in [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h) that has **f_mode** in the file struct and tried to print it out and received big numbers, like 1208647709 or 917507

[The results after running dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHRU.png)

Here is my code

```
struct task_struct *task_list;
struct fdtable *        fdt = NULL;
unsigned int process_count = 0;
int fd_i;
char  tmpbuf[256];
char * process_path = "";
struct path files_path;
unsigned int mode_path;
char *cwd;
for_each_process(task_list) {
    pr_info("Process: %s\t PID:[%d]\t State:%s\n", 
            task_list->comm, task_list->pid,
            get_task_state(task_list->state));
    if (task_list->files == NULL) continue; 
    fdt = files_fdtable(task_list->files);
    int i=0;
    while(fdt->fd[i] != NULL) { 
        files_path = fdt->fd[i]->f_path;
        mode_path = fdt->fd[i]->f_mode;
        cwd = d_path(&files_path,buf,100*sizeof(char));
        printk(KERN_INFO "Open file with fd %d  %s **mode: %d**", i,cwd, mode_path);            
        i++;
    }
}
```

Could someone review and support me about this problem?

Comment: Header [fs.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L108) defines macros FMODE_READ and FMODE_WRITE which denotes r/w flags for `f_mode` field. So you could test the field for given flags.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev
Thanks for your comment. Do you know about the "u" flag for both RW access, where is its value in fs.h file?

Comment: RW access means that both `FMOD_READ` and `FMODE_WRITE` flags are set.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev
I added some logical operators to detect Read and Write access.

if(fdt->fd[i]->f_mode & FMODE_READ){
                access_mode = "read";
            }else if(fdt->fd[i]->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE){
                access_mode = "write";
            }

These codes work but I am not sure how to do with RW access. I put
 (fdt->fd[i]->f_mode & (FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE )) but it doesn't help. Could you review and support me to figure out a way to check RW access? Regards

Comment: You could **extract both flags** using `f_mode & (FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE)`. Then **switch** for the result of that expression: 1. Result equal to `FMODE_READ` means "r". 2. Result equal to `FMODE_WRITE` means "r". 3. Result equal to expression `FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE` means "u".

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev
Your suggestion is very helpful. I have tried and see that it works for Read&Write mode. 
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from Tsyvarev:
extract both flags using `f_mode & (FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE)`. Then switch for the result of that expression:

1. Result equal to `FMODE_READ` means "r".
2. Result equal to `FMODE_WRITE` means "w".
3. Result equal to expression `FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE` means "u".